# Error C2248 cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a simple Class with boost socket as member, and I'm trying to pass IP address to it's constructor, which gives me the compile error.

```
Error 2 error C2248: 'boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>::basic_io_object' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>'
```

However if i remove the std::string ip argument from it's constructor it's works fine.
Any idea why It's not compiling

```
class TestConnection 
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket tcp_socket_;
public:
    TestConnection(boost::asio::io_service &io, std::string ip):tcp_socket_(io)
    {

    }
    ~TestConnection()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        std::string test_ip = "192.168.1.10";
        TestConnection testconn = TestConnection(io_service, test_ip);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> TestConnection testconn = TestConnection(io_service, test_ip);

In the above line you actually attempt to invoke `TestConnection` copy-constructor, which is unavailable, because `tcp_socket_` member is non-copyable. Instead, you could write that line as follows:

```
TestConnection testconn(io_service, test_ip);
```

Comment: can you tell why does it work when i remove the extra std::string argument?

Comment: @Pritesh Acharya, this is a non-standard extension in MSVC. Try compiling with GCC, and it will fail in both cases.